# How to connect to cassandra nodes created by docker-compose via python datastax

Tags: python, docker-compose, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I am using the following `.yaml` file to create a 2 node Cassandra cluster.

```yaml
version: "3.3"
networks:
  cassandra:

volumes:
  cassandra_seed_data:
  cassandra_node_data:

services:
  cassandra-seed:
    image: cassandra:3.11
    restart: "no"
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "5m"
        max-file: "3"
    container_name: cassandra-seed
    networks:
      - cassandra
    expose:
      - "7000"
    ports:
      - target: 9042
        published: 9042
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - cassandra_seed_data:/var/lib/cassandra 
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS: "cassandra-seed"
      CASSANDRA_NUM_TOKENS: 4
      CASSANDRA_START_RPC: true

  cassandra-node:
    image: cassandra:3.11
    restart: "no"
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "5m"
        max-file: "1"
    container_name: cassandra-node
    hostname: cassandra-node
    networks:
      - cassandra
    expose:
      - "7000"
    ports:
      - target: 9042
        published: 9043
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - cassandra_node_data:/var/lib/cassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS: "cassandra-seed"
      CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS: cassandra-node
      CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS: cassandra-node
      CASSANDRA_START_RPC: true
      # CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH: SimpleSnitch
      CASSANDRA_NUM_TOKENS: 4
      # CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME: cluster
      # CASSANDRA_DC: dc
      # HEAP_NEWSIZE: 32M
      # MAX_HEAP_SIZE: 4M
```

This runs all nice, which can be verified by

```bash
docker exec cassandra-seed nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.96.2  71.27 KiB  4            100.0%            ce5de211-63be-44c7-8f3c-bf0a18270a40  rack1
UN  192.168.96.3  71.41 KiB  4            100.0%            a6eae6e9-be77-4c34-ad0b-12333d2630a7  rack1
```

and the output of `docker-compose ps``

```bash
docker-compose ps                        
NAME                COMMAND                  SERVICE             STATUS              PORTS
cassandra-node      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   cassandra-node      running             7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9160/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9043->9042/tcp
cassandra-seed      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   cassandra-seed      running             7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9160/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9042->9042/tcp
```

Now I am using the DataStax python driver and i would like to connect to these nodes.

It says there [DataStax](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/getting_started/)

> The set of IP addresses we pass to the Cluster is simply an initial set of contact points. After the driver connects to one of these nodes it will automatically discover the rest of the nodes in the cluster and connect to them, so you don’t need to list every node in your cluster.

```py
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

cluster = Cluster(**{'contact_points': ['0.0.0.0'], 'port': 9042, 'compression': 'lz4', 'protocol_version': 4})
cluster.connect(wait_for_all_pools=True)
```

and then getting:

```
INFO:cassandra.policies:Using datacenter 'datacenter1' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (via host '0.0.0.0:9042'); if incorrect, please specify a local_dc to the constructor, or limit contact points to local cluster nodes

INFO:cassandra.cluster:New Cassandra host <Host: 192.168.96.3:9042 datacenter1> discovered

WARNING:cassandra.cluster:Failed to create connection pool for new host 192.168.96.3:9042:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3175, in cassandra.cluster.Session.add_or_renew_pool.run_add_or_renew_pool
  File "cassandra/pool.py", line 402, in cassandra.pool.HostConnection.__init__
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1620, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connection_factory
  File "cassandra/connection.py", line 831, in cassandra.connection.Connection.factory
  File "/Users/ekotsal/miniconda3/envs/cbd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cassandra/io/libevreactor.py", line 267, in __init__
    self._connect_socket()
  File "cassandra/connection.py", line 898, in cassandra.connection.Connection._connect_socket
OSError: [Errno None] Tried connecting to [('192.168.96.3', 9042)]. Last error: timed out

WARNING:cassandra.cluster:Host 192.168.96.3:9042 has been marked down
```

Meanwhile in my `docker-compose` logs, nothing appears as happening.
How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Do you run your python from a container on the same network as the cluster?
Can you try using a container name instead of the contact point, for example:

```py
cluster = Cluster(['containerName'], port=9042)...
```

You could also try the following with the container name and use that IP instead in your code:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <containerName>
```

Comment: I am not inside the same network unfortunately. Using the `docker insepct` container ip's unfortunately does not work.

Comment: what does it look like when you start cassandra? do you have better luck setting the broadcast IP this way?:
`docker run -d -p "7191:7191" -p "7000:7000" -p "7001:7001" -p "9160:9160" -p "9042:9042" -e CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=xx.xx.xx.xx cassandra...`
Other examples here:
https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra

Comment: it also appears you have both listen address and broadcast address set to cassandra-node, if this is a cloud instance you'd typically configure gossip on a private subnet and client connunication on a public IP by setting listen address to the private IP and rpc and broadcast to the public IP.

Comment: you are right about the public instance and that's how it is configured there, but i cannot control it. I have to leverage the network created by compose

Comment: After all the studying i did, this appears to be a connection timeout issue. I read https://stackoverflow.com/a/32086996/3292827 but i was unable to set it via the SocketOptions link provided.